# Сквозное выполнение блоков case

Tags: c

Расскажите, как происходит сквозное выполнение блоков case в этом примере. Когда используется не сквозное выполнение, это оператор аналогичен множественному if-else: если символ не совпадает с меткой, то этот блок case не выполняется, и происходит переход к следующему блоку. А что происходит в случае вложенных блоков case?

Пусть символ c не равен '0', тогда соответствующий кейс не выполняется. Тело этого кейса - последовательность вложенных кейсов для случаев '1', '2', ..., '9'. Почему программа пройдет через все эти случаи, если они являются телом case '0', которое не должно выполняться? Если это происходит, значит, значения меток не важны, и программа выполняет все блоки подряд. Но это, очевидно, не так. Что я не так понял?

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    switch(c){
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            ndigit[c-'0']++;
            break;
        case ' ':
        case '\n':
        case '\t':
            nwhite++;
            break;
        default:
            nother++;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Тело этого кейса - последовательность вложенных кейсов для случаев '1', '2', ..., '9'.` Почему вы так решили?

Comment: Я в этом не уверен, но выглядит это так. У K&R не объясняется, как работают эти кейсы, сказано только, что это обычные метки. То есть метка case '0': указывает на код, который выполнится, если c == '0'. Это подтверждает работа одиночных кейсов: если значения совпали, то код выполняется, если не совпали - не выполняется. case '0' просто содержит в себе другие кейсы, которые не должны выполняться, если c != '0'.

Comment: То что вы написали `case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':` это не значит что получились какие-то вложенные кейсы. Скорее всего это тоже самое что написать эти же кейсы на строке каждый, только и всего.

Comment: И как работают кейсы на каждой строке? Вот те, что ниже. Пусть символ равен '  '. Этот кейс выполняется, значит, надо увеличить число пробельных символов. Переходим к case '\n'. Он не выполняется. Переходим к case '\t". Он не выполняется. Как мы доходим до инкремента переменной?

Comment: Они работают как условие `или`. Вам уже написали это в ответе. Если у вас символ пробел - то находится `case ' '` и выполняется `nwhite++;`

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему они выполняются как ИЛИ. Если символ "пробел", то блок case '\t', в котором инкрементируется переменная, не должен выполняться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор `switch` можно<sup>1</sup> расписать с использованием меток и передачи управления `goto`:

```
if(c == '0') goto case_0;
else if(c == '1') goto case_1;
else if(c == '2') goto case_2;
else if(c == '3') goto case_3;
else if(c == '4') goto case_4;
else if(c == '5') goto case_5;
else if(c == '6') goto case_6;
else if(c == '7') goto case_7;
else if(c == '8') goto case_8;
else if(c == '9') goto case_9;
else if(c == ' ') goto case_;
else if(c == '\n') goto case_n;
else if(c == '\t') goto case_t;
else goto case_default;

case_0: 
case_1: 
case_2:
case_3: 
case_4:
case_5: 
case_6: 
case_7: 
case_8: 
case_9:
    ndigit[c-'0']++;
    goto switch_exit; // break
case_:
case_n:
case_t:
    nwhite++;
    goto switch_exit; // break
case_default:
    nother++;
    goto switch_exit; // break

switch_end:
```

Заметим, что любая передача управления на `case_0` - `case_8` эквивалентна передаче управления на `case_9`, поскольку они будут указывать на одну и ту же инструкцию. Таким образом, после первого совпадения, инструкции будут выполнятся до тех пор, пока не встретится выход из `switch` (`break` или `goto switch_end` в транслированном примере)

---

Интересно также посмотреть, какой код будет генерировать компилятор. Даже при отключенной оптимизации, код слабо напоминает прямую трасляцию `switch` на `goto`, но все-таки, есть определенные сходства. Допустим, у нас есть следующий фрагмент кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case 2: case 7: case 17:
            printf("2-7-17\n");
        case 3: case 11: case 19:
            printf("3-11-19\n");
        case 5: case 13: case 23:
            printf("5-13-23\n");
        default:
            printf("Wow\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    foo(i);

    return 0;
}
```

gcc видит, что границы не очень большие и резервирует место для хранения метки под каждый случай от 0 до 23:

```
    .file   "main.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "2-7-17"
.LC1:
    .string "3-11-19"
.LC2:
    .string "5-13-23"
.LC3:
    .string "Wow"
    .text
    .globl  foo
    .type   foo, @function
foo:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    cmpl    $23, -4(%rbp)
    ja  .L2
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movq    .L4(,%rax,8), %rax
    jmp *%rax
    .section    .rodata
    .align 8
    .align 4
.L4:
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L3 # 2
    .quad   .L5 # 3
    .quad   .L2 
    .quad   .L6 # 5
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L3 # 7
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L5 # 11
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L6 # 13
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L3 # 17
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L5 # 19
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L2
    .quad   .L6 # 23
    .text
.L3:
    movl    $.LC0, %edi # .string   "2-7-17"
    call    puts
.L5:
    movl    $.LC1, %edi # .string   "3-11-19"
    call    puts
.L6:
    movl    $.LC2, %edi # .string   "5-13-23"
    call    puts
.L2:
    movl    $.LC3, %edi # .string   "Wow"
    call    puts
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   foo, .-foo
    .section    .rodata
.LC4:
    .string "%d"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movl    $.LC4, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    __isoc99_scanf
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    foo
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 5.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@
```

clang закручивает гайки куда более изощренным способом:

```
    .text
    .file   "main.c"
    .globl  foo
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   foo,@function
foo:                                    # @foo
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
.Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %edi, %eax
    movl    %edi, %ecx
    subl    $23, %edi               # Compare i with 23
    movl    %ecx, -8(%rbp)          # 4-byte Spill
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
    movl    %edi, -16(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
    ja  .LBB0_4                     # prints "Wow\n" (when i > 23)
# BB#6:
    movl    $131204, %eax           # imm = 0x20084
    movl    -8(%rbp), %ecx          # 4-byte Reload
    btl %ecx, %eax
    jb  .LBB0_1                     # prints "2-7-17\n"
# BB#7:
    movl    $526344, %eax           # imm = 0x80808
    movl    -8(%rbp), %ecx          # 4-byte Reload
    btl %ecx, %eax
    jb  .LBB0_2                     # prints "3-11-19\n"
# BB#8:
    movl    $8396832, %eax          # imm = 0x802020
    movl    -8(%rbp), %ecx          # 4-byte Reload
    btl %ecx, %eax
    jb  .LBB0_3                     # prints "5-13-23\n"
    jmp .LBB0_4                     # prints "Wow\n"
.LBB0_1:
    movabsq $.L.str, %rdi           # .asciz    "2-7-17\n"
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   printf
    movl    %eax, -20(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
.LBB0_2:
    movabsq $.L.str1, %rdi          # .asciz    "3-11-19\n"
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   printf
    movl    %eax, -24(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
.LBB0_3:
    movabsq $.L.str2, %rdi          # .asciz    "5-13-23\n"
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   printf
    movl    %eax, -28(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
.LBB0_4:
    movabsq $.L.str3, %rdi          # .asciz    "Wow\n"
    movb    $0, %al 
    callq   printf
    movl    %eax, -32(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
# BB#5:
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
.Ltmp3:
    .size   foo, .Ltmp3-foo
    .cfi_endproc

    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
.Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.Ltmp5:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.Ltmp6:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movabsq $.L.str4, %rdi
    leaq    -8(%rbp), %rsi
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   __isoc99_scanf
    movl    -8(%rbp), %edi
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)         # 4-byte Spill
    callq   foo
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
.Ltmp7:
    .size   main, .Ltmp7-main
    .cfi_endproc

    .type   .L.str,@object          # @.str
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.L.str:
    .asciz  "2-7-17\n"
    .size   .L.str, 8

    .type   .L.str1,@object         # @.str1
.L.str1:
    .asciz  "3-11-19\n"
    .size   .L.str1, 9

    .type   .L.str2,@object         # @.str2
.L.str2:
    .asciz  "5-13-23\n"
    .size   .L.str2, 9

    .type   .L.str3,@object         # @.str3
.L.str3:
    .asciz  "Wow\n"
    .size   .L.str3, 5

    .type   .L.str4,@object         # @.str4
.L.str4:
    .asciz  "%d"
    .size   .L.str4, 3


    .ident  "clang version 3.6.2 (tags/RELEASE_362/final)"
    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

Для того, чтобы соотнести метку с введенным числом, clang генерирует следующую маску (на примере "2-7-17"):

```
100000000010000100
^         ^    ^   
17        7    2
```

После чего проверяет наличие бита с помощью инструкции `btl`.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Можно*, но, разумеется, исключительно в учебных целях.

Comment: Вот это интересно. Я где-то упустил, что если выполнилось хотя бы одно совпадение, то далее будут выполняться все инструкции, и этого надо избегать, расставляя break.

Comment: `break` в `switch`, вообще говоря, забавная штука. С одной стороны, можно наворотить кучу багов из-за него. С другой стороны, он (а, точнее говоря, его отсутствие) дает возможность писать подобные штуки. Так что со `switch` нужно быть предельно осторожным. Я могу добавить ассемблерный листинг в ответ, чтобы показать, что он практически без изменений транслируется в ассемблер (и в этом его плюс).

Comment: А какие баги могут быть из-за break? Листинг асм я бы посмотрел.

Comment: Компилятор не будет ругаться, если убрать `break`. А это чревато выполнением еще одной ветки кода.

Comment: @typemoon, не учел я, что даже без опимизации компилятор не будет транслировать один в один; my fault, как говорится. Но зато листинги интересные привел - взгляните.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш switch

```
    switch(c){
      case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
      case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
          ndigit[c-'0']++;
          break;
      case ' ':
      case '\n':
      case '\t':
          nwhite++;
          break;
      default:
          nother++;
          break;
    }
```

можно записать в виде условий

```
if (c == '0' OR c == '1' OR c == '2' OR c == '3' OR c == '4' OR c == '5' OR c == '6' OR c == '7' OR c == '8' OR c == '9')
{
          ndigit[c-'0']++;
}
else if (c == ' ' OR c == '\n' OR c == '\t')
{
          nwhite++;
}
else
{
          nother++;
}
```

То есть, так называемые "вложенные блоки" это подобие ИЛИ в условиях.

P.S. Синтаксиса Си не знаю, возможно, что-то не так указал.

Comment: Вы упустили **маааааленькую** деталь. Там разные переменные, которые во втором блоке вы случайно забыли. Так что сокращение для третьего блока неприменимо.

Comment: @D-side, спасибо! Поправлю ответ сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
switch(c){
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            ndigit[c-'0']++;
            break;
        case ' ':
        case '\n':
        case '\t':
            nwhite++;
            break;
        default:
            nother++;
            break;
    }
}
```

это упрощенная запись вот этого:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
switch(c){
        case '0': 
            ndigit[c-'0']++;
            break;
        case '1': 
            ndigit[c-'0']++;
            break; 
        // и т.д 10 раз
        // ...
        case ' ':
            nwhite++;
            break;
        case '\n':
            nwhite++;
            break;
        case '\t':
            nwhite++;
            break;
        default:
            nother++;
            break;
    }
}
```

Согласитесь, глупо писать одно и тоже 3 или 10 раз. Поэтому кейсы группируются в один блок. А как вы их пишете

```
case ' ':
case '\n':
case '\t':
```

или

```
case ' ': case '\n': case '\t':
```

значения не имеет.

Comment: И мне интересно, почему сгруппированные кейсы работают так, как написано во втором куске кода. Похоже на какой-то недокументированный синтаксический сахар.

Comment: В мое время это описывалось достаточно понятно. По каким мануалам вы сейчас изучаете Си - мне неведомо.

Comment: По Кернигану и Ричи.

Comment: @typemoon, это не является синтаксическим сахаром. Это самое обысное определение метки. Количество пробелов не играет роли.

Answer (score 1):

В этом фрагменте кода все перечисленные метки case '0', case '1', ..., case '9' помечают один и тот же участок кода

```
switch(c){
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
        ndigit[c-'0']++;
        break;
    //...
```

Предложение `switch` передает управление на ту метку, которая соответствует вычисленному значению заданного выражения. Поэтому, например, если значение выражения будет равно `'1'`, то и `switch` предложение передаст управление на метку `case '1'`.

Когда выражение вычислено, то совершенно неважно, сколько меток задано в `switch` предложении. Важно лишь существует ли соответствующая метка для вычисленного значения или же не существует.  Другие метки просто не рассматриваются. Они как бы "не интересуют" предложение `switch`.

Представьте себе, что где-то в программе у вас имеется следующий фрагмент кода

```
Label1:
Label2:
Lbael3:
Label4:
Label5:
    puts( "Hello typemoon" );
```

И вы решили передать управление на предложение `puts`. Вы можете сделать это следующим образом:

```
goto Label3;
```

Для предложения `goto` совершенно неважно, какие вообще метки имеются перед предложением с `puts`. Ему лишь важно, существует ли метка `Label3`. Если такой метки нет, то компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке, даже несмотря на то, что есть другие метки перед предложением с `puts`. Если же такая метка есть, то программа скомпилируется, и управление от `goto` будет передано на предложение, помеченное меткой `Label3`.

Разница между этим примером и примером с предложением `switch` состоит лишь в том, что предложение `switch` выбирает для `goto`  подходящую метку во время выполнения программы в зависимости от значения вычисленного выражения. И если соответствующей метки нет, то передает управление на метку `default`, если та присутствует, либо, в случае ее отсутствия, передает управление на следующее предложение после `switch`